# Initialise Stream Chat Flutter in part of the application (widget tree)

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

I'm creating an application with chat functionality and I'm using Stream Chat Flutter. I followed the official tutorial: https://getstream.io/chat/flutter/tutorial/

The tutorial says to use the `builder` in `MaterialApp` and wrap the child route with `StreamChat`.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, widget) {
    return StreamChat(
      client: client,
      child: widget,
    );
  },
  home: StreamChannel(
    channel: channel,
    child: const ChannelPage(),
  ),
);
```

And to then call `client.connectUser`.

I want to know how I can efficiently disconnect and reconnect a user and make sure the web socket connections are closed, without wrapping my whole application with `StreamChat`.

Most of the Stream examples show how to initialise and connect users for the whole application and then they stay connected. But I only want to initialise and connect to Stream when the chat portion of the app is opened.

Answer (score 8):

The solution to this requires two things:

- understanding routing in Flutter
- and managing the connection status of your Stream user depending on the current route

It is important to understand that a WebSocket connection is only made to Stream when you call `connectUser`. And that there is only a small overhead when wrapping your entire widget tree with `StreamChat`. The WebSocket connection is then closed when you call `disconnectUser`.

[This official guide demos three ways](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/initialize_stream_chat_widget_tree/) to manage a Stream Chat Flutter connection and only have Stream chat in a part of an application (widget tree) and explains everything in detail.

1. [Builder and Connect/Disconnect User](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/initialize_stream_chat_widget_tree/#option-1-builder-and-connectdisconnect-user)
2. [A Nested Navigator](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/initialize_stream_chat_widget_tree/#option-2-a-nested-navigator)
3. [Flutter Navigator 2.0 - Using GoRouter](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/initialize_stream_chat_widget_tree/#option-3-navigator-20---using-gorouter)